# C++ mutex in lambda results in crash

Tags: c++, lambda, mutex

I would like to acquire a lock from a mutex inside a lambda but that results in a crash.

```
class ControlWindow
{
public:
    explicit ControlWindow();
    ~ControlWindow();
private:
    void createMyWindow();
    std::mutex m_mutex;
};

void ControlWindow::createMyWindow()
{
    ...
    Button* btn = new Button([this](void*) {
            m_mutex.lock(); // this fails with the error below
            {...}
            m_mutex.unlock();
    });
    ...
}
```

> The error thrown is: Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF05FD3FB8 in
>   MyApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::system_error at memory
>   location 0x000000AD753FE070. Debug Error!

The mutex also doesn't work if it is a global variable in the cpp file. Other member variables can be accessed fine and in the debugger the mutex looks the same in the lambda and outside the lambda.

How do I access the mutex correctly?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. What is `Button`? When is the lambda called? What is the lifetime of the `ControlWindow`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My error was that I tried to lock the mutex twice from the same thread. The passing into the lambda works fine. Also the use of `std::lock_guard<>` would be appropriate. Indeed the calling code would have been needed to spot my error here.

Comment: If it is legitimate to already have that mutex locked from somewhere else in the thread then look at `std::recursive_mutex` instead.